# How can I retrieve the room list in my office 365 tenant using a rest API /Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph, office365apis

I would like to retrieve the room list in my tenancy (If possible filter it based on only if the email contains e,g xyz.com.
Is this possible.
Will using graph api an option? If yes any resources would be helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the link [findRooms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findrooms?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http),

We can get all the rooms in the tenant using the below Graph API:

```
GET /me/findRooms
GET /users/{id}/findRooms
```

To get the Specific Room using email ID, we can use the below API:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms(RoomList='Building2Rooms@contoso.onmicrosoft.com')
```

References:

1. Find Rooms: [user: findRooms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findrooms?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)
2. Find RoomList: [user: findRoomLists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findroomlists?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

**Note: Above APIs are in BETA mode.**

Comment: Thanks and i went through those articles.When i test findrooms i can see all the list of rooms in my tenant but what i want is specific rooms that contains email address ending with e.g xyz.com.
Any ideas what the query could look like and is there any other way apart from using this api?